# Firefox and IE breaks line with exact pixels

Tags: html, css, image, html-lists

So, I have something like this:

[image: chrome works correctly]

4 objects with exactly 76x76px within a 320px holder.
In Chrome, you can see above, it works just fine.
But in Firefox and IE9 I get something like this:

[image: firefox wont work correctly]

with the same sized `<ul>`

[image]

I only get it to display correctly if I resize the `<li>`

[image]

Why is that? The image size is actually 76x76 and Chrome renders it correctly.
Thanks in advance!

---EDIT---

So I was on my way to provide you guys with a jsFiddle and I realized that the simple code worked fine there for all browsers. So after some "removing all the code until I find the problem" I found it! haha
It was caused by these two style lines combined applied to all the sidebar:

```
letter-spacing: 1.6px;
font-family: Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
```

If I just remove one of these, it works correctly, the combination of both where the problem. So just setting `font-family: Arial;` (I know, weird solution, right?) to the `<ul>` did it!

Thanks all.

Comment: Are you able to provide a live example for us to inspect?  Or perhaps throw some code out on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: seems pretty likely that it's something going on with your margins, but yeah, without any code there's really no way to tell.

Comment: Hey! Read my post EDIT! And thanks. Also, how do I close the question?

Comment: @Derik: Answer the question yourself and accept your answer, see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/. If you really want to delete it see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was on my way to provide you guys with a jsFiddle and I realized that the simple code worked fine there for all browsers. So after some "removing all the code until I find the problem" I found it! haha
It was caused by these two style lines combined applied to all the sidebar:

```
letter-spacing: 1.6px;
font-family: Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
```

If I just remove one of these, it works correctly, the combination of both where the problem. So just setting `font-family: Arial;` (I know, weird solution, right?) to the `<ul>` did it!

Thanks all.

Comment: Not that surprising actually. Font settings, especially when it comes to line-height and letter-spacing, affect a bunch of inline content layout. If you have white-space on top of unregulated font settings you can get into a whole world of pain.

Comment: I'm going to bet that's not the root of the problem. Do you have a doctype?

Comment: ah, jsfiddle. what would we do without it?

Comment: I do have a doctype. I was surprised, never had a similar problem, actually. Will keep that "inline affectivity" in mind. And I love jsfiddle, don't know what we would do without it! haha